# Door repairable?

Tags: wood-repair, door

[image]

Friend got a little rough original doors would like to repair lost some slivers of wood, what do you think?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  For a painted surface I would simply use a wood filler to level the gaps.

Comment: Just FYI the "anyone know of a good place in Seattle" part of your question is considered "off-topic" on this site so I have removed it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this should be repairable.  I would probably use a good 2-part epoxy (like West or Entropy) to repair it because it can fill any gaps caused by missing material.  Also it does not require clamping pressure like normal wood glue does.

The most challenging part of this repair will probably be making sure that the panel does not bond to the epoxy used to repair the frame.  The panel will need to "float" in the frame to accommodate seasonal wood movement.  (Unless the panel is MDF/plywood, in which case it can be glued in place.)